# Why reading a json format file resulting all the records going to _corrupt_record in pyspark

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark

I am reading data from an api call and the data is in the form of json like below:

```
{'success': True, 'errors': \[\], 'requestId': '151a2#fg', 'warnings': \[\], 'result': \[{'id': 10322433, 'name': 'sdfdgd', 'desc': '', 'createdAt': '2016-09-20T13:48:58Z+0000', 'updatedAt': '2020-07-16T13:08:03Z+0000', 'url': 'https://eda', 'subject': {'type': 'Text', 'value': 'Register now'}, 'fromName': {'type': 'Text', 'value': 'ramjdn fg'}, 'fromEmail': {'type': 'Text', 'value': 'ffdfee@ozx.com'}, 'replyEmail': {'type': 'Text', 'value': 'ffdfee@ozx.com'}, 'folder': {'type': 'Folder', 'value': 478, 'folderName': 'sjha'}, 'operational': False, 'textOnly': False, 'publishToMSI': False, 'webView': False, 'status': 'approved', 'template': 1031, 'workspace': 'Default', 'isOpenTrackingDisabled': False, 'version': 2, 'autoCopyToText': True, 'preHeader': None}\]}
```

Now when I am creating a dataframe out of this data using below code:

```
df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize(\[data\]))
```

I am getting only one column which is _corrupt_record, below is the dataframe o/p I am getting. I have tried using **multine is true** but am still not getting the desired output.

```
+--------------------+
|     \_corrupt_record|
\+--------------------+
|{'id': 12526, 'na...|
\+--------------------+
```

Expected o/p is the dataframe after exploding json with different columns, like id as one column, name as other column and so on.

I have tried lot of things but not able to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I have made certain changes and it worked.

1. I need to define the custom schema
2. Then used this bit of code

   ```
   data = sc.parallelize([items])
   df = spark.createDataFrame(data,schema=schema)
   ```

And It worked.

If there are any optimized solution to this please feel free to share.